# Real wave functions for periodic systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In QM the wave function, $\psi(z)$, satisfies the (one dimensional) Schrodinger equation,$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 \psi}{d z^2} + V(z) \psi(z) = \varepsilon \psi(z).$$ For real potentials this means that you can always take $\psi(z)$ to be either purely real or purely imaginary.

What about the case of an infinite periodic lattice (the Bloch boundary condition, $\psi(z+L) = e^{iqL}\psi(z)$ seems to mean the wave functions are now complex quantities). Is this not true any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that you can always take $\psi(z)$ to be either purely real or purely imaginary

but it doesn't mean that you *have* to. In this specific instance we don't, because it's more useful that way.

More specifically, in a periodic system the hamiltonian is vastly degenerate, and if you really want to, you can build (vaguely) localized real-valued eigenfunctions, but this means that those eigenfunctions no longer share the translation invariance of the hamiltonian (you get translation-invariant eigenfunctions, and you get real eigenfunctions, but no one ever said you're guaranteed both at the same time), and that one is much more useful, so we go with that instead.

Comment: But it's convenient numerically to be able to take eigenfunctions as real.

Comment: Not as convenient as only needing to calculate over a single unit cell instead of over the whole (infinite) crystal.

Comment: According to Griffiths, for the Kronig-Penney model, the wf may be written as $\psi(z) = C \left( \sin kz + e^{-iKa} \sin k(L-z) \right) $. I'm not sure if you are saying you can get a real wf from this?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that if you do not have translation-invariant wavefunctions, you're going to need to simulate the entire crystal, and if you do have them then you only need to calculate one single unit cell. Whatever convenience you'd get from real-valued wavefunctions doesn't even begin to register.